# Where is Prestashops Maintanence mode setting stored?

Tags: prestashop

I'm having an issue with my website at the moment and I wish to enable maintenance mode. I'm unable to login but I do have access to the database. Which table is this located in?

Also, Prestashop.com is down for me including the forums so I can't look there... My web host is also unsure...

I know this isn't really a proper thing to ask but I'm unsure where else I could ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the table `ps_configuration` under the name `PS_SHOP_ENABLE`